# Parsing texts and put it in HTML tags at spectfic location

Tags: java

I am having text file containing one record in each line, example is given below:

```
946352705   U.S.A.  UNIMOX DRUGS PVT. LTD.  "65 West Alisal St, salinas, CA 93901"
946357899   U.S.A.  NIL DRUGS PVT. LTD. "86 East Alisal St, salinas, CA 93905"
```

I want to generate HTML file using data of above text file for each record using java

**Expected Output for one Line Record:**

```
<doctypehtml1>
<html>
<body>
<code>946352705</code>
<i>U.S.A.</i>
<B>UNIMOX DRUGS PVT. LTD.</B>
<p>"65 West Alisal St, salinas, CA 93901"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could either use JSP or `String.format`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Comment: How are the fields separated? Tabs?

Comment: Is anyone here to answer my question...

Comment: Hii is anyone here to answer my question...?

Comment: fields are seperted using multiple or single spaces, that is spaces are not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually parse text using jquery (requirement is to have at-least two spaces between new record as your data contains strings that have one space.)

```
var lines = $('.label_im_getting').html().split('\n');
var htmlData = "<doctypehtml1><html><body>";
$.each(lines, function(index, line) {
  var words = line.split("  ");
 htmlData += '<code>' + $.trim(words[0]) + '</code>' + '<i>' + $.trim(words[1]) + '</i>' + '<B>' + $.trim(words[2]) + '</B>' + '<p>' + $.trim(words[3]) + '</p>';
});
htmlData +='</body></html>';
$("#output").html(htmlData);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cHU86/134/)

JAVA code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String rawData = "946352705  U.S.A.  UNIMOX DRUGS PVT. LTD.  \"65 West Alisal St, salinas, CA 93901\" \n946357899  U.S.A.  NIL DRUGS PVT. LTD.  \"86 East Alisal St, salinas, CA 93905\"";
    String[] lines = rawData.trim().split("\n");
    StringBuilder htmlData = new StringBuilder("<doctypehtml1><html><body>");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.trim().split("  ");
        htmlData.append("<code>" + words[0].trim() + "</code>");
        htmlData.append("<i>" + words[1].trim() + "</i>");
        htmlData.append("<B>" + words[2].trim() + "</B>");
        htmlData.append("<p>" + words[3].trim() + "</p>");
    }
    htmlData.append("</body></html>");
    System.out.println(htmlData.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Dipali, but I want Java code for generating html files...Will you please try it for java

Comment: @NileshDeshmukh What DipaliVasini has given you should be easily translated to Java. First line is a simple string.split("\n"), second line is just a string, then you have a for-loop to iterate over your lines from the previous split. And then you split the line into words and add them to your htmlData string. You should be able to do this 'translation' yourself without any troubles.

Comment: Yes...got it..Thanks Chewtoy

Comment: you can accept the answer if it helped. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work